# How to get empty input from the user in Java

Tags: java, user-input

How do I get user input while asking the user *Do you want to continue or not?*

If the user press *Enter* then how do I go to the next instructions so I compare it to do other tasks?

Comment: can any body plz look at my question

Comment: What do you want the user to enter if he does not want to continue?

Comment: i just wanna know if i be taking integer input then if user want to skip that and press enter then i have to ask him next question .....

Comment: Consider re-writing your question and putting in enough information so that we can fully understand it, because right now it's somewhat confusing.  One link that has helped me learn to ask answerable questions is: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: @user615599 - 1) if you don't take the time to write coherent questions, you are unlikely to get the answers that you need.  2) most SO folks don't respond positively to newcomers demanding answers; e.g. *"I JUST WANNA KNOW ..."*.

Comment: After having read the question, the answer, and all the comments, I still don't know what it is all about.

Answer (score 2):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.nextLine();
```

**Edit:** Sorry, misread question (well question title and body is different). You can ask the user like this:

```
System.out.print("Do you want to continue? ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

if (scanner.next().toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
    // continue...
} else {
    // don't continue
}
```

So when a user types in "y" or "Y" it will continue. Otherwise, it won't.

Comment: I JUST WANNA KNOW like String a = scan.next();

Comment: If you just want to know, then you already know it: `String userResponse = scanner.next();`. Your question title, body and your comments do not match, they ask for different things. Sorry, this is all I can do.

Comment: amazed you could do that much given the nature of the question.  1+ for trying.

Comment: Now that I re-read my answer, I figured `if (!...) { // stop the code }` would be a better way to do it. Thanks for the +1, did my best.

Comment: My guess is he needs a while loop with an if block inside of it -- the while loop to repeat, the if block to set the boolean that is tested in the while's condition block.

Comment: Yes, but he would then have to iterate through an array of strings to print out something new every time the loop runs. In such cases, where I need to print out something long, I use a procedural method and create my own function `checkContinue()` and place it wherever I need to ask the user the continue. I think that makes a better code for readability. I don't know what others would think, I would like to know more about how to do this correctly.